# how to make an icon spin with i tag in html5 through css3

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code

```
<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5'>
    <label for='captcha-code'>Captcha Code: </label>
    <span id='captcha-text'></span>
    <i class='captcha-refresh icon-spinner9 pointer'></i>
</div>
```

I am using icomoons as for displaying the icons. What I am trying to achieve is whenever a person clicks on this `<i class='captcha-refresh icon-spinner9 pointer'></i>` i want it to rotate like as a loader so that we can show that something is processing I have tried many css3 transitions. All those transitions are only being applied to the `div` tags and not on `i` tags.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use can easily achieve this using simple CSS `keyframes`. I've create a class called `icn-spinner`, assuming that it will contain icon. This class has animation called `icn-spinner` and will rotate 2 times. You can make it infinite if you want. Just replace `2` with keyword `infinite`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-spin').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('icn-spinner') //remove class to stop animation
  });
});
```

```css
i {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.icn-spinner {
  animation: spin-animation 0.5s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin-animation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="js-spin"> ♠ Click </i>
```

Comment: How to give it an infinite loop ?

Comment: `animation: spin-animation 1s infinity;`

Comment: This is what i wanted, it's perfect only i want to give it an infinite loop how to attain it ?

Comment: i am, having a problem attaining using JQuery on click, it's not working that way :(

Comment: Updated the answer. If you want animation then add class `icn-spinner`, for to remove animate just remove it. Hope that solves.

Comment: Thanks @Kalpesh that was super perfect. That's what i needed. Worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: Awesome, buddy! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using javascript/jquery with CSS. Javascript/ Jquery is needed to toggle the class of the 'i' element having the icon. Below is the complete solution.

Here is the HTML code that you provided:

```
<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5'>
    <label for='captcha-code'>Captcha Code: </label>
    <span id='captcha-text'></span>
    <i class='captcha-refresh icon-spinner9 pointer'></i>
</div>
```

Jquery code to add the class 'icn-spinner' on click of the element having 'js-spin' class in its class-list.
Here for this, you need to import jquery in your project.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-spin').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('icn-spinner') //remove class to stop animation
    });
});
```

Here is the code for CSS styling.
Without 'animation-timing-function' the spinner will rotate but it will be not linear.
The animation starts at 0deg and ends at 360deg.

```
i {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.icn-spinner {
    animation: spin-animation 1s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin-animation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```